# TypeScript empty array initialized in constructor is undefined at runtime

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

I noticed that whenever if have the following code :

```
class ClassA {
   constructor() {
       this.MyArray = []; // or this.MyArray = new Array(someNumber);
   }

   MyArray: ClassB[];
}

class ClassB {
  constructor(public Name : string) { }
}
```

The property MyArray is undefined at runtime. This is not the case if I initialize the array with some value. Why is that and how can I avoid it ?

**Update**

Actually that seems to work [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20ClassB%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor%28public%20Name%20%3A%20string%29%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aclass%20ClassA%20%7B%0A%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.MyArray%20%3D%20[]%3B%20%2F%2F%20or%20this.MyArray%20%3D%20new%20Array%28someNumber%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20MyArray%3A%20ClassB[]%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Avar%20variable%20%3D%20new%20ClassA%28%29%3B%0Avariable.MyArray.push%28new%20ClassB%28%22ok%22%29%29%3B%0Aalert%28variable.MyArray.length%29%3B%0A). I'll try to isolate the issue more accurately, I'm beaten by that sporadically. Might be closure issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the `classA`, `B[]` is not valid syntax.

Check this from [typescript playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20ClassA%20%7B%0A%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.MyArray%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20or%20this.MyArray%20%3D%20new%20Array(someNumber)%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20MyArray%3A%20B%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20ClassB%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(public%20Name%20%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D)

---

In the updated link it is `ClassB[];` not just `B[]`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it ! I made a mistkae while writing my question